# how to get width and height of image from url without downloading?

Tags: ios, uiimageview, uiimage, nsurl, sdwebimage

I'm using SDWebImage for showing images inside cells. But it is perfect mached to frame of UImageView that I'm doing in code below:

```
NSString * s =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"url of image to show"];
        NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:s];
        [cell.shopImageView sd_setImageWithURL:url];
```

My UIImageView is size 50x50.

For example image from url is size 990x2100 and my image is not displaying well in the frame given.
In this case when hight is bigger, I want to resize my image  by proper height ratio to match width 50.

Is there a way to check image's size from url without downloading it and allocating memory in awful way?

Comment: You could try to set up a `HEAD` request, but you'd have to talk to the guy that runs your server to make sure image dimensions are returned in the request.

Comment: yeah... it's not gonna happen, API is not changeable but thanks for advice

Comment: Then what you're asking for isn't possible.  You can't get information about the image without the image itself, so that rules out your on-device solution.  The only other route would be to have the server analyze the image and send that as metadata, but if the server APIs can't change, then you're stuck.

Answer (score 18):

You can fetch this data from URL header, in **Swift 3.0** use below code

```
 if let imageSource = CGImageSourceCreateWithURL(url! as CFURL, nil) {
     if let imageProperties = CGImageSourceCopyPropertiesAtIndex(imageSource, 0, nil) as Dictionary? {
          let pixelWidth = imageProperties[kCGImagePropertyPixelWidth] as! Int
          let pixelHeight = imageProperties[kCGImagePropertyPixelHeight] as! Int
          print("the image width is: \(pixelWidth)")
          print("the image height is: \(pixelHeight)")
       }
   }
```

Comment: Adding this gives error "use of unresolved identifier CGImageSourceCreateWithURL"

Answer (score 7):

Try messing with the different contentMode options to get the look you want. One example could be `cell.shopImageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;` That will just make the image fit nicely, but won't actually resize the image view.

Here are your contentMode options: [UIViewContentModes](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/uiview_class/uiview/uiview.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/UIViewContentMode/)

An alternative could be something along the lines of this:

`NSData *data = [[NSData alloc]initWithContentsOfURL:URL]; 
UIImage *image = [[UIImage alloc]initWithData:data];
CGFloat height = image.size.height;
CGFloat width = image.size.width;`

You can then set your imageView height/width depending on the ratio of the image's height/width.

Comment: Hey, I need to resize cell when image is bigger then 50x50. eg if image is 1000x1500 I need UIImageView frame 50x75

Comment: Oh I see, I guess I misunderstood the question. Maybe something along the lines of this: `            NSData *data = [[NSData alloc]initWithContentsOfURL:URL];
            UIImage *image = [[UIImage alloc]initWithData:data];` and then check the image height/width. Or did you not want to create a UIImage?

Comment: yeah I didn't want to create one to make memory low usage on this task :)

Comment: I wouldn't expect it to take that much memory if you create it locally, but I gotcha. Well I can't think of a way how to at the moment. I will update my answer in case anyone else finds it useful.

Answer (score 1):

- I don't know how to get the size of your image from URL without downloading the image.
- But I can provide you some code snippet to make your UIImageView frame proportionally after the image is downloaded.

  ```
  NSData *data = [[NSData alloc]initWithContentsOfURL:URL]; // -- avoid this.
  ```
- If you use the above method to download image it will block your UI. So please avoid it.

  ```
  [cell.shopImageView ....]; // -- avoid this method.
  ```
- As you're using **SDWebImage**, I guess it will have some dedicated methods to download the image first. So you can use that method to download the image instead of using UIImageView categories method as you used above.
- After you downloaded the image. Try something like below.
- **Code Snippet**
- Assume the image is downloaded and the object is 'theImage', and 'imageView' as your cell imageview

  ```
  float imageRatio = theImage.size.width/theImage.size.height;
  float widthWithMaxHeight = imageView.frame.size.height * imageRatio;
  float finalWidth, finalHeight;
  if (widthWithMaxHeight > imageView.frame.size.width) {
      finalWidth = imageView.frame.size.width;
      finalHeight = imageView.frame.size.width/imageRatio;
  } else {
      finalHeight = imageView.frame.size.height;
      finalWidth = imageView.frame.size.height * imageRatio;
  }

  [imageView setFrame:CGRectMake(xOffset, yOffset, finalWidth, finalHeight)];
  [imageView setImage:theImage];
  ```

Answer (score 1):

```
 let ImageArray =  ((arrFeedData[indexPath.row] as AnyObject).value(forKey: "social_media_images") as? NSArray)!
 var ImageURL: String =  ((ImageArray[0] as AnyObject) as? String)!
 ImageURL = ImageURL.addingPercentEscapes(using: String.Encoding.ascii)!
   let imageUrl = URL(string: ImageURL)
   let imageData = try Data(contentsOf: imageUrl!)
    let image = UIImage(data: imageData)
print("image height: \(image?.size.height)"
  print("image Width: \(image?.size.width)")
```

Comment: It gives Exception (file could not be opened)